# When is didReceiveMemoryWarning actually called

Tags: iphone, ios, memory, ios6, didreceivememorywarning

I've never personally seen `didReceiveMemoryWarning` called before. Is there a known threshold of memory usage where it gets called?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's called when the system has low memory, then you need to purge your `UIViewController`.

You can simulate a memory warning in the Simulator: `Hardware > Simulate Memory Warning` and see what happens.

If you are supporting prior versions to iOS6 it's important to take note of the following from [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> Prior to iOS 6, when a low-memory warning occurred, the
>   `UIViewController` class purged its views if it knew it could reload or
>   recreate them again later. If this happens, it also calls the
>   `viewWillUnload` and `viewDidUnload` methods to give your code a chance to
>   relinquish ownership of any objects that are associated with your view
>   hierarchy, including objects loaded from the nib file, objects created
>   in your `viewDidLoad` method, and objects created lazily at runtime and
>   added to the view hierarchy. On iOS 6, views are never purged and
>   these methods are never called. If your view controller needs to
>   perform specific tasks when memory is low, it should override the
>   `didReceiveMemoryWarning` method.

About the threshold, I try not to exceed 12MB of memory.

Answer (score 3):

No. It is called when springboard feels that there are too many resources using memory on the device. Depending on how much stuff other apps are using on your phone, it can happen sooner or later. You can never reliably calculate or rely on when it will happen.

Also be warned, because the memory reported in tools like allocations is not necessarily correlated to the footprint of your app, so it can look like you are not using much, but you may still get this warning.

Answer (score 2):

from the documentation , when the system determines that the amount of available memory is low then this method is called. system determines low memory itself , when your app allocations exceed the amount of memory available to your app then this method is called. Please refer http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

On newer Xcode/Simulator versions, it is under the `Debug` tab of Simulator, and you can also press `Cmd+Shift+M`, but be sure that Simulator app is focused.

[image: 1]